# Linux for simply one task: watch youtube

Tags: distribution-choice, youtube, kiosk

I have tested some Linux versions for my kid's laptop. Old Samsung notebook, Samsung N10.

I need do only one task: run youtube videos with no lag. Or setup an Android on it. I also tried RemiX-OS and Pheonix-Os, both don't load up. Works only 4.4.

I setup also Android-X86 on that laptop, run Play Store app for youtube and all is working very fast.

I tested with mint-xfce on browser. Videos is lagging in Chromium browser.

Maybe there is app in Linux like on Android?

Is Puppy Linux, smallest Linux distro can solve this problems?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you expect to run wirelessly or with wire?

Comment: You can try SMTube from Smplayer.

Answer (score 2):

For something fast, linux needs drivers dedicated to the graphic card of your computer.

So without any info about your RAM size, CPU speed, GPU I can only say :

Try the last Ubuntu, which should support most of the graphic card and specific hardware (with firefox) :
https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

They claim :

> Recommended system requirements:
>
> ```
> 2 GHz dual core processor or better
> 2 GB system memory
> 25 GB of free hard drive space
> Either a DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media
> Internet access is helpful
> ```

Or try Fedora :
https://getfedora.org/en/workstation/download/

They claim :

> you may install Fedora Workstation to a laptop or desktop computer
>   that has at least 1 GHz processor, 1 GB RAM, and 10 GB space
>   available.

Comment: I have 2GB ram, 2 cores Intel Atom CPU, Standart HDD, Video intel hd. It is a 2008 year model :)

Comment: But latest distro versions dont eat more resourses? And with desktop envoirment need to take for old Laptop?

Answer (score 0):

Try Bodhi Linux Standard release if your CPU is 64 bit. Install Bodhi Linux legacy if your CPU is 32 bit. Install Firefox using the app centre situated in the taskbar or simply by using Synaptics Package Manager.

PS: I know that the question is old but I'm answering it for people who might visit this webpage looking for this age old problem.